# Convert JSON object to simple variables in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a very heavy JSON with lots of parameters which I want to convert to a Java object containing just a few of them.

Direct conversion such as this

```
DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class);
```

is not an option.

How can I access individual fields within objects (just `value` under `date` and `type` under `attributes` under `completion_date`)?
JSON example:

```
{"results":[
    {"date":{
        "attributes":{
        "type":null},
        "value":"December 13, 2010"},
    "is_structured":"No",
    "completion_date":{
        "attributes":{
            "type":"Anticipated"},
        "value":"March 2016"},
     ....
```

Comment: "not an option"? Why?

Comment: May be you are talking about JSON.parse look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: So you have your json as String and you want to access given property directly? Or you have some sort of Map or JsonObject?

Comment: As a String or a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to directly convert your input to the expected Object you could create a `JSONObject` from your input like

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(input);
```

and then navigate from there exactly to the attribute you need e.g.:

```
root.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("is_structured");
```

EDIT: (receive `value` under `date`)

```
root.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("date").getString("value");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And what is the syntax for getting a sub-field, for example `date.value`?

Comment: Therefore you have to navigate into the deeper `JSONObject`. See my edit

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for taking your time to explain it to me, I definitely grasp the matter now!

Answer (score 0):

You can have just the fields you need in your bean definition. For example, given the following JSON

```
{
  firstName: 'It',
  lastName: 'works',
  ignoreMe: '!!!'
}
```

the bean definition does not contain `ignoreMe`:

```
public class Contact {
    public String firstName; // setter and getter
    public String lastName;  // setter and getter
}
```

But it works with Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Contact contact = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(new File("test.json")), Contact.class);
System.out.println("It worked!");
```